# About git-new-workdir branches syncing

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-worktree

I am using git-new-workdir script to manage my branches but the branch apparently do not synchronize automatically. I have a repo with three branches (master, branchA and branchB). First, I cloned the repo with:

```
git clone git://myreposite.com/project.git
```

Second, I use git-new-workdir to split my branches

```
git-new-workdir project branchA branchA
git-new-workdir project branchB branchB
```

Now I have project, branchA and branchB directories.
Suppose someone else also had cloned my repo from other computer and checked out branchA, modified a file, committed and issued a `git push --all`.

Thus, now I have to updated my branchA. So, I issue a `git pull --all` from master branch directory and I would expect that all my branches got updated instantly, but they didn't. When check the modified file on branchA directory nothing changed.

What am doing wrong?

Comment: Note that Git 2.5 will replace `git-new-workdir` with `git checkout --to=<path>`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309

Answer (score 3):

That’s not how it works. While you have multiple working directories, they are not automatically updated when the checked out branches are updated. You have to do that manually yourself.